# Can't get Android ContentProvider to work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put together a simple app to help me understand the content provider but I can't get it to work. I want to insert data into a database but I think the problem I have is somewhere with the URI.

** I am trying to follow a similar pattern as shown in the Udacity tutorials

Here is what I have
Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.simplecontentprovider">

     <provider
        android:authorities="com.example.android.simplecontentprovider.app"
        android:name=".data.MyContentProvider" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ContentProvider:

```
  public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    MyDatabaseHelper mOpenHelper;

    private static final int NAME = 1;

    // Creates a UriMatcher object.
    private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

    static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {

        final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        final String authority = MyDataContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY; // Value = com.example.android.simplecontentprovider.app

        matcher.addURI(authority, MyDataContract.PATH_TABLE, NAME); //PATH_TABLE = tblUserData
        //matcher.addURI(authority, MyDataContract.PATH_TABLE + "/*", NAME);

        return matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        mOpenHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strings, String s, String[] strings1, String s1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match){
            case NAME:
                return MyDataContract.UserDetailsEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("UNKNOWN URI: " + uri);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        Uri returnUri;

        switch (match) {
            case NAME: {
                long _id = db.insert(MyDataContract.UserDetailsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
                if ( _id > 0 )
                    returnUri = MyDataContract.UserDetailsEntry.buildtblUserDetailsUri(_id);
                else
                    throw new android.database.SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return returnUri;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String s, String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String s, String[] strings) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and finally the MainActivity

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MyDataContract.UserDetailsEntry.buildtblUserDetailsAll("MyTestName");

    Log.e("RESOLVER URI: ", uri.toString());

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MyDataContract.UserDetailsEntry.COLUMN_NAME, "MyTestName");

    try {
        resolver.insert(uri, values);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("RESOLVER INSERT: ", e.toString());
    }
```

When I run it through the debugger I get this message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://com.example.android.simplecontentprovider.app/tblUserData/MyTestName
```

this is the default value for the insert in the content provider. I am not sure if I am missing the authority part

Comment: I think you're supposed to place the your <provider> inside <application>.

Comment: Thanks Dave, moving the <provider> inside <application> worked.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.simplecontentprovider">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.android.simplecontentprovider.app"
            android:name=".data.MyContentProvider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```